# android custom soft keyboard intercepting ime_action

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently making a soft keyboard of my own in android and having a hard time getting the ime action selected - (`IME_ACTION_SEARCH` or `IME_ACTION_DONE` etc.).

For instance, if an user enters google search than the action button should be a search button and if it's a sms then it'll be a line break. How can I differ between them?

I've tried looking for it in the with no luck.

```
onCreateInputView(){}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [getCurrentInputEditorInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#getCurrentInputEditorInfo()) on your [InputMethodService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html). Then you can inspect the EditorInfo's [imeOptions property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#imeOptions).

```
int imeOptions = mInputMethodService.getCurrentInputEditorInfo().imeOptions;
switch (imeOptions&EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE:
                // None
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                // Go
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                // Serach
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                // Send
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                // Next
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                // Done
        }
```

Comment: I am having same problem.but getCurrentInputEditorInfo(). throwing null ?